# jqGrid XML generating with xmlJsonClass, cdata cells

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using this code in order to generate XML from my grid's cells values:

```
var grid =  $("#MyGrid");
        var dataFromGrid = grid.jqGrid ('getRowData');            
        var xml_string = '<rows>' + xmlJsonClass.json2xml ({MyGridRow: dataFromGrid}, '\t') + '</rows>';
```

Inside my grid I have cells that contain XML tags (for example:

```
     <cell1><b><h1>aaa</h1><b></cell1>
```

I want this data of a specific column to be inside a CDATA (so I will be able later to parse it as XML). 
How can I add a CDATA tag to the generation of "xmlJsonClass.json2xml"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/JsonXml.js#L42) of the `json2xml` function, which you use, consists of about 60 lines. It seems to me that the easiest way to implement your requirements would be to modify the code.

If you add 3 lines of code

```
else if (v[m].charAt(0) === "<") {
    xml += toXml("<![CDATA[" + v[m] + "]]>", m, ind+"\t");
}
```

you will see the results in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExportInXmlWithCDATA.htm).